# Construction—Как бы не...—Why is "не" used?

Tags: грамматика

In Constructions of the type КАК БЫ НЕ..., what exactly does the "не" add to the phrase. I'm looking for a literal interpretation from those of you that know both English and Russian at a very high level.

For example—

Я боюсь, как бы он не забыл зайти в аптеку.

Правительство боится, как бы этот закон не привел к увлечению бюджетных мест.

What is a literal translation of these sentences, and why do we need "не" at all?

Comment: In order to understand the meaning you can drop "не". *Я боюсь, как бы он не забыл зайти в аптеку. / **I am afraid he would forget to visit the pharmacy.***

Comment: I don't think there's literal translation or parsing to this, this is just a pattern of one type of subjunctive expression. May be there's a philological explanation which reveals historical logic behind it now lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The sense of the expression.

I think the sentence in question is a clearly **pessimistic transformation** of this optimistic one (where **не** directly negates the verb):

> Надеюсь, он ***не*** забудет зайти в аптеку. (I hope he won't forget to
>   visit the drugstore.)

The original version expresses **uncertainty** based on some possibility of things going wrong:

> Боюсь, **как бы** он **не** забыл зайти в аптеку.
>
> I'm afraid he might forget to visit the drugstore.
>
> I'm afraid that maybe he'll have forgotten to visit the drugstore.

2. Form of the expression and how negation **не** works in Russian version.

Typical English translation doesn't use direct negation, present in the Russian expression. But what is the negation **не** aimed at? Despite its position right before the verb, it **does not directly negate** its meaning but refers to *unwanted* (or *unexpected* - in similar cases of doubtful speculation) *possibility* of its action. It seems possible to give a *close-in-sense* isolated expression where **не** negates the action of an *additional* verb, while the existing verb stays **in the affirmative** (considering **не** originally didn't directly negate it):

> как бы... **не**... ~ (мне) **не** хотелось бы, чтобы...

It works here independently of the emphasizing addition **Я боюсь** (I'm afraid):

> (Я боюсь вот чего:) **не** *хотелось бы, чтобы* он забыл зайти в аптеку.

Correspondingly, an English version of the above can be given with a similar direct negation:

> (I'm afraid,) *I would **not** want him to somehow* forget to visit the
>   drugstore.

Answer (score 10):

The presence of the particle *бы* suggests it is the conditional mood. This mood has several meanings, and since here there is no actual condition (like *if* or *when*), it has **desiderative** meaning, that is it expresses our desire, what we *wish*. Keeping this in mind, it becomes much more clear why *не* is used in such constructions: the word *wish* is implied but not expressed openly, other verbs are used instead.

So in *Я боюсь, как бы он не забыл зайти в аптеку*, the verb *боюсь* does not mean actual fear or awe, but it is the hope that he will **not** forget to visit the drug store. That is, the implied meaning of this sentence is actually *Я **надеюсь**, что **он не забудет** зайти в аптеку.*

In other words, in such sentences the second part expresses the desirable state of things in which the unwanted situation does **not** occur.

Comment: After I asked the question I thought more about it. Your answer is great. Personally I came up with something like—I'm afraid (of) how he could not forget to go to the store. Meaning--I'm afraid because "how can it be that he won't go". I fear that there is now way he will avoid this. It seems to me that this is a pretty close comparison to English, although strangely worded, no doubt. :)

Comment: Btw, I'm of the opinion that the "wish" meaning of бы is really just a modal/conditional.

Answer (score 3):

"Как бы не" is a traditional construct that is often utilized to convey negative meaning.

Let's look into the details of your example.
"Правительство боится, как бы этот закон не привел к увлечению бюджетных мест." - "The government is afraid that this law can lead to the increase of subsidized enrollment(?)"

Now let's see if we can drop the "не":

"Правительство боится, как бы этот закон привел к увлечению бюджетных мест." - this phrase is clumsy and its meaning is unclear. Why? Because the word "боится" implies **negative** meaning - but the particle "не" is missing, so we are not sure what exactly the government is afraid of.

What if we change the negative verb into a **neutral** one?

"Правительство *думает*, как бы этот закон не привел к увлечению бюджетных мест." - "The government is thinking that this law can lead to the undesired increase of subsidized enrollment". This new phrase is pretty close in meaning to the original one.

"Правительство *думает*, как бы этот закон привел к увлечению бюджетных мест." - "The government is thinking how to make this law to increase the subsidized enrollment".

You see, now dropping the "не" completely changed the meaning!

And more examples:

"Как бы так" - "That's the way it is"

"Как бы не так" - "No way!"